# Return value of system() function call in C++, used to run a Python program

Tags: c++, python, linux, system

I am working on Linux with code that makes a `system()` call to run a python program. I am interested in the value returned by this function call to understand how the python program execution went.

So far, I have found 3 results:

- When the python process completes successfully, value returned by system() is 0
- When the python process is killed mid-execution (using `kill -9 pid`), value returned by system() is 9
- When the python process fails on its own due to incorrect parameters, value returned by system() is 512

This does not fit with what I've read about [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function.

Furthermore, the code for the python program being invoked shows that it exits with `sys.exit(2)` when any error is encountered, and `sys.exit(0)` when execution completes successfully.

Could anyone relate these two? Am I interpreting the return value in a wrong manner? Is there some Linux processing involved that takes the argument of the `sys.exit()` function of the python program and returns value of `system()` based on it?

Comment: How are you invoking the python program? i.e. with `system("/usr/bin/env python /path/to/script");`?

Comment: `system("python progname.py arg1 arg2 arg2");`
Python has already been added to PATH

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The exit code of the program you call can be fetched with `WEXITSTATUS(status)` as per the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system). Also see the manual page for [`wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

```
int status = system("/path/to/my/program");
if (status < 0)
    std::cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
else
{
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
        std::cout << "Program returned normally, exit code " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Program exited abnormaly\n";
}
```

Comment: How to do that in Windows 7? What is the header file in which WIFEXITED is defined?

Comment: @CroCo Windows doesn't have the same thing when it comes to exit codes, it's a [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) thing.