# lua os.execute() return wrong value

Tags: lua

have a problem:

```
 local stat = assert(os.execute("/usr/bin/pgrep -f 'tail -F /opt/aaa' >& /dev/null"))
 print(stat)  --> 0
```

But when I type `pgrep -f 'tail -F /opt/aaa' >& /dev/null` in bash, and then call `echo $?` it returns 1. Has anybody encountered this before, or know the reason why ;-)  what happened?

Comment: Which Lua version are You using?

Comment: 5.1.4 on RHEL5_x86_64 platform

Comment: In Lua 5.2 you get the status. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.execute

Comment: @lhf I had try this under 5.2.2, but it does't return the correct value too. It returns `true` and `exit`

Comment: After exit there is a numerical exit code.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't seem to be a Lua problem to me, `os.execute` is just wrapping a call to `system`:

```
 static int os_execute (lua_State *L) {
    lua_pushinteger(L, system(luaL_optstring(L, 1, NULL)));
    return 1;
 }
```

If you try the `C` alternative you have the correct result code?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main ()
 {
    char command[100];
    int result;

    strcpy( command, "/usr/bin/pgrep -f 'tail -F /opt/aaa' >& /dev/null" );
    result = system(command);

    return(0);
  }
```

Comment: I gave it a try, but unfortunately it return 0 too.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931134/return-value-of-system-function-call-in-c-used-to-run-a-python-program?rq=1 this related python question answers _in part_ your question